# C standard library corner case

Tags: c, visual-c++, stdio

Is the following program a valid C program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    fwrite("x", 1, 1, stderr);
    fflush(stderr);
    fgetc(stderr);
    fwrite("y", 1, 1, stderr);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I try to read from stderr.

When I compile it in Visual C++ 2008, and run it, I get the following output:

```
xy
```

which makes sense. However, when I redirect stderr to a file (`test.exe 2> foo.txt`), I get a
"Debug Assertion Failed" window with the  message: "Inconsistent Stream Count. Flush between consecutive read and write". Adding a `fflush` between the read and write does fix the problem.
(This happens in debug build. In release builds, the second write silently fails).

Is this behavior correct, or is this a <strike>compiler</strike> library bug? I couldn't find anywhere any rules describing when reads or writes are illegal in C.

Comment: Reading from an output stream is undefined behaviour. And what on earth would you expect it to do?

Comment: One note that it would not be a compiler bug but a library implementation bug.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - I don't believe reading an output stream should cause UB.  According to the Opengroup, this should just cause `fgetc` to fail and set errno to `EBADF` (see http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgetc.html)

Comment: @Neil: if reading from stderr is undefined behavior, that's the answer. Do you have a reference for it? (I would expect it to fail in a defined way).

Comment: @Amnon Can't find it - maybe I'm imagining it. The standard does not seem to specify explicitly what happens if you read from an output stream . It certainly does not specify that errno is set to EBADF, however.

Comment: I believe Neil's right (the result is UB), but I don't think there's a reference for it -- the standard simply doesn't attempt to define the result of reading from a stream opened only for output, so the result is UB. If you want to get technical, the reference is §4/2: "Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C99 says in 7.19.5.3 (`fopen`), paragraph 6:

> When a file is opened with update mode (`'+'` as the second or third character in the above list of `mode` argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function [...], and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

Congratulations for discovering this corner case in practice. The library implementation is completely correct, since you violate the *shall* quoted above.

And by the way, it is not uncommon to read from `stderr`. This is useful when `stdin` and `stdout` are redirected and no terminal is available. Although C99 doesn't guarantee it to be readable, I remember some cases on POSIX-like systems where this had actually been done.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question at all.

Comment: It answers the question 99%. Theoretically the "unless" clause at the end may imply that a failed read doesn't count, but I don't think anybody thought of this case, hence it's undefined.

Comment: @Amnon It says "When a file is opened with update mode" - what makes you think stderr is opened in that mode? And you cannot call positioning functions on stderr.

Comment: `stderr` is one of the three streams that is already opened when `main` starts. To explain the behavior, I assumed that `stderr` had been opened as if by calling `fopen`. I didn't find a reference that reading from a write-only stream leads to undefined behavior, so I happended to read the documentation of `fopen`, and I felt this could explain the behavior well enough.

Comment: Why shouldn't I be able to call positioning functions on `stderr`? 7.19.9.4p2 explicitly mentions the effect of calling `ftell` on a text stream.

Comment: @Neil: there's nothing stopping the user from running the program with stderr redirected to a r/w stream. Anyway, I'm now convinced that the code is too borderline (I thought that any sequence of file operations on an valid file handle was defined-- even if it was defined to set error flags).

Comment: @Roland text stream != stderr.